# Springboot unable to load js files from resources folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have uploaded my project on the project to git 
https://github.com/gitekiras/spring-boot-gradle-mvc

What i am not able to get right is that i am not able to load the css and js from the resources folder.

When i put it in webapp folder, i am able to get every thing working but according to the tutorials, i should put them in the static folder in resources.

but when i do so i am not able to load the css and js on page.

Can any one say what i am missing ?

Also: when i see in browser logs - it shows that it is trying to find the js and css files as `application/json`. I am not sure what i have done wrong here.

Comment: If you extract the resulting jar file after your build completes, do you see the static assets?

Comment: no the build folder contains the folders but not the files.

Comment: In Maven I typically define a copy resources build configuration to copy all the resources to the artifact.

Comment: Have a look at my pom.xml in the build config.  I'm not familiar with Gradle, but I imagine there's an equivalent.  https://github.com/pgrimard/boot-angular-starter/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly [overrode](https://github.com/gitekiras/spring-boot-gradle-mvc/blob/7dea569e02095642b9fb35ff3e2f8e4dd9bbf8ed/src/main/java/com/ekiras/config/AppConfiguration.java#L16) the default behavior by adding your own `@EnableWebMvc` - see [Spring MVC auto-configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration). Remove the `@EnableWebMvc` (and also unneeded resource handler for `/resources/**`) and it will work.

Comment: just removed this code and still getting the same error

Comment: thanks a ton, i read that line almost 10 times, but didnt notice it.

Comment: I have found solution how to make resources load using spring mvc with @EnableWebMvc annotation , tag me if any one needs help.