# Spring Boot App returns 401 for all static content in resources even while loading images

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot webapp with some security configurations for different routes. The project has some resources listed as follows:

- resources/
- static/

  - css/
  - img/
  - js/
  - libs/
- templates/
- config-files/
- application.properties

The problem is that while I can load my views (without styles) through the template engine (thymeleaf), all requests to static contents return a 401 code.

Now, I searched and found a lot of content regarding this issue. The funny part in here is that neither js, libs nor css files are being loaded, BUT images ARE being displayed. To clarify: even images are returning 401 codes while being displayed.

Some of the already asked questions I've found are:

- [Spring Boot not serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content)
- [SpringBoot 401 UnAuthorized even with out security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232071/springboot-401-unauthorized-even-with-out-security)
- [Springboot unable to load js files from resources folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544267/springboot-unable-to-load-js-files-from-resources-folder)
- [Spring Test returning 401 for unsecured URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554285/spring-test-returning-401-for-unsecured-urls)

And I've dug around a lot of spring documentation

---

So here are my config, security & login files by th, which I've tampered a lot but stills nothing works:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:mongo-config.xml"})
public class ProjectConfiguration implements  WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler(
            "/img/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/libs/**")
            .addResourceLocations(
                    "classpath:/static/img/",
                    "classpath:/static/css/",
                    "classpath:/static/js/",
                    "classpath:/static/libs/");
}
```

---

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Security Config");
    http    .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**","/css/**","/img/**","/libs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/userManagement", "/userManagement/**", "/rest/auth").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin", "/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/managementSettings", "/managementSettings/**").hasRole("MANAGEMENT")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "DEMO", "MANAGEMENT")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler( CustomSimpleURLAuthenticationSuccesHandler())
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
            .addFilterAfter(AjaxRedirectFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
            .headers()
                .httpPublicKeyPinning()
                .addSha256Pins("*********************","*************************")
                .includeSubDomains(true)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(10000);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/js/**","/css/**","/img/**","/libs/**");
}
```

---

```
<div class="content">
    <img style="margin:auto" class="img-responsive" th:src="@{/img/logo.png}"/>
</div>
```

---

I would like to point out a few things:

1. @{/img/logo.png} seems to be the correct endpoint to request from view because if I change anything here images do not display
2. In the same way, if I change any route from the security or config files images do not display, so routes must be correct in there too
3. If I open the browser developer tools and check the network tab it says: "Failed to load response data", but if double click the file it does open in fact the js resource as plain text loaded from the server [dev tools capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qwCy.png) & [plain text jQuery display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiyM6.png)

---

So, with all this being said, how can I load all my static files in my view? I don't mind having custom or default paths as long as I'm able to access my files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and hours trying to solve the problem, the solution was removing an outdated API REST code that was messing with the whole project security stuff.

The typical stuff to expect from a project migration

Answer (score 0):

You must configure security on assets URLs to permitAll, like the fifth sector on this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources. I guess.

Comment: That's the same I have already tried that with my java config and it does not work